# nyc ReferenceError: cov_vyj5vtdds is not defined with worker threads

Tags: node.js, multithreading, nyc

My code is throwing an exception when I'm trying to get the test coverage of my project using `nyc`.
I'm also using the library [node-worker-threads-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-worker-threads-pool) to create a pool of worker threads.

I created a minimal example to emulate the behavior. With this example the behavior is the same, when I execute the test, everything works, but when I try to get the coverage I have an exception.

This is the file where I create the new thread

```js
// thread.js
const os = require('os');
const { DynamicPool } = require('node-worker-threads-pool');

const Pool = new DynamicPool(os.cpus().length, { shareEnv: true });

const someFunction = async (params) =>
  await Pool.exec({
    task: async function() {
      const { params } = this.workerData;
      console.log('params', params);
      return params;
    },
    workerData: {
      params,
    },
  });

module.exports = {
  someFunction,
};
```

And this is the test

```js
// thread.test.js
const { someFunction } = require('../thread');

describe('Some Function in another thread', () => {
  it('it works', async () => {
    const params = 1;
    const res = await someFunction(params);
    expect(res).to.be.eq(params);
  });
});
```

When I execute `NODE_ENV=test mocha --exit 'thread.test.js' --maxWorkers=2` the test passes, but when I tried to get the coverage with nyc `NODE_ENV=test nyc --reporter=text --reporter=html --reporter=lcov mocha --exit 'thread.test.js' --maxWorkers=2` the following exception appears:

```js
  1) Some Function in another thread
       it works:
     ReferenceError: cov_vyj5vtdds is not defined
      at Object.task (evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:40)
      at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:204
      at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:20)
      at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:311:38)
      at MessagePort.<anonymous> ([worker eval]:11:29)
      at MessagePort.onmessage (internal/worker/io.js:78:8)
      at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (internal/per_context/messageport.js:11:10)
  From previous event:
      at PoolWorker.work (node_modules/node-worker-threads-pool/src/pool-worker.js:22:12)
      at DynamicPool.runTask (node_modules/node-worker-threads-pool/src/pool.js:110:47)
      at DynamicPool.exec (node_modules/node-worker-threads-pool/src/dynamic-pool.js:51:17)
      at someFunction (src/modules/templates/thread.js:1:1577)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/modules/templates/thread.test.js:6:23)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Uh. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-worker-threads-pool: "*Notice: If task is a function, you can NOT access variables defined outside the task function! If you do want to use external data, use workerData to pass some cloneable data.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after doing a little of research I understand that basically `nyc` creates variables with random names to count the coverage and insert those inside of all the functions and it uses cloture to access them.

The problem is that it's not possible to use cloture inside of a thread. It's imperative to use the `workerData` property to send the arguments to the `Worker` constructor. That's why I was having the `ReferenceError` exception.
[Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

I didn't really found a solution. But I did find an alternative to `nyc` that also uses `istambuljs` which is `c8`. I no longer have those exceptions with `c8`.

Comment: you saved me a lot of time, thank you! My solution, similarly to your, was just add /* istanbul ignore file */ at a very top of file which was added as worker's thread!